# How can I solve this terminal sudo update error/ or software updater error?

Tags: updates, xubuntu, update-manager

Everytime I sudo update in the terminal, it gives me this message W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmjdebruijn/darktable-release/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found. And whenever I use software updater it says Internet connection problem, when actually my Internet is perfectly fine. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Answer (score 1):

That is because the person who maintains the PPA has not yet made a package for Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn, which is what you have. All you can do is remove the PPA.